# Ant gives "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" when run through Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

I've set up a job in Jenkins that runs ant, it gives this error:

```
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Unpacking https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.10.3-bin.zip to /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/default-ant on Jenkins
[my_project] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/default-ant/bin/ant dist
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
```

Why is this happening ?

What can I do to fix it ?

Note,
If I ssh in to the build server, go to the jenkins workspace, and manuall run

```
 /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/default-ant/bin/ant dist
```

the build succeeds.

Jenkins reports `java.runtime.version   1.8.0_131-b11` and on the build machine:

```
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 -> this always points to a mismatch in versions. You are trying to run code on a Java version that is older (and not backwards compatible) with the one you used to compile the code.

Comment: @Stultuske So, why is that happening ? Why does invoking ant manually work ? Where to I click in Jenkins to fix it ? (Note that the error appears to  when ant itself is invoked, so before anything deals with any code I have written or am responsible for)

Comment: You are trying to run your code with lower version of java than the required one. It's probably Jenkins having its own java version or using a different JDK than the system one which you see in console

Comment: In the job configuration I think there is a JDK dropdown where you can select one of the JDKs installed if there are multiple ones. It doesn't always use the system one

Comment: @Veselin.Davidov As noted, this happens when ant itself it trying to run, not my code. i.e. the ant versjon requires java 8, but for an unknown reason, ant is invoked by something not supporting java 8. (whilst as mentioned, if I run the exact same ant command manually on the build machine, it works.). I've not found any drop down menu where I can select the JDK, and since jenkins reports the `java.runtime.version   1.8.0_131-b11` , jenkins is also running under java 8.

Comment: When executing thriugh Jenkins, can you run "ant -diagnostics". It will show you which JDK version ant is using during the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, as hinted by in the comments by @VeselinDavidov

The newest ant (v 1.10 and newer) only supports Java 8, however the $PATH was set to include a place with Java 7 (unknown as to why JDK 7 was the 1. item in the $PATH when ant was run through jenkins, but not when running it manually outside jenkins)

To resolve:

1. Go to the configuration of the job in Jenkins
2. Go to the "Build Environment" section
3. Check the "With ant" checkbox which also expands to more configuration options.
4. Select the proper "Ant version" and "JDK version"

If the proper "JDK version" is not available/installed, do this first:

1. Go to "Manage Jenkins" from the jenkins front page
2. Go to "Global Tool Configuration" and click "JDK Installations"
3. Define/install the relevant JDK version.
4. Go back to the job and set up ant with this new JDK version.

Alternatively, if Java 7 is sufficient, install and use ant version 1.9.x, which supports Java 7.